# Eclipse Headless Builds

Tags: eclipse, build-automation

We have an eclipse workspace at work with projects relying on CDT, Android NDK, SWIG and Java. We have the following builders under the Builders section of each projects' property page:

1) SWIG Builder
2) CDT Builder
3) Android Resource Manager
4) Android Pre Compiler
5) Java Builder
6) Android Package Builder
7) Scanner Configuration Builder
8) Post Build Step

Granted that some of these, are custom builders - I was wondering if there is a way to initiate a headless build from the command line that runs all of the above builders in sequence.  I am aware that CDT and Java headless builds are perfectly doable separately, but I am not yet convinced that a more complex project such as the above can be built from the command-line using eclipse. Has anyone done anything similar? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update in case anyone else is hitting the same wall and wondering what I ended up doing - as far as I can tell the answer to the above question is no. I ended up using Ant make files to call the builders in order which worked out pretty well.